# Как в Opencart программно задать seo_url, по которому определяется ссылка на товар

Tags: opencart, seo, ссылки, alias

У меня вопрос следующего характера. В админке в карточке редактирования каждого товара есть вкладка "Данные". В ней есть поле SEO URL. Именно по ней определяется ссылка на товар в браузере. Я делаю выгрузку из 1с, читается xml-файл с товарами. Как мне программно задать SEO URL для каждого выгружаемого товара?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape('ваш seo url') . "'");
```

я хочу поделиться как seo_url определять в функциях addProduct и editProduct в административном разделе. Нужно просто определить во входном массиве этих функций 'keyword'=>'my-seo-url'. Кому интересно вот как правильно осущесвляется вызов этих функций(addProduct/editProduct):

```
$product_id = $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct(array(
                'name'=>trim($product_data['name']),
                'model'=>trim($product_data['model']),
                'price'=>$product_data['price'],
                'status'=>$activity,
                'quantity'=>$product_data['quantity'],
                'product_category'=>array('0'=>$category_id),
                'main_category_id'=>$main_category_id,
                'stock_status_id'=>$available,
                'keyword'=>trim($product_data['product_code']),//trim(str_replace('-','',$product_data['product_code'])),
                'noindex'=>1,

                'sku' => '',
                'upc' => '',
                'ean' => '',
                'isbn' => '',
                'jan' => '',
                'mpn' => '',
                'location' => '',
                'minimum'=>1,
                'date_available'=>date('Y-m-d',time()),
                'manufacturer_id'=>0,
                'weight'=>0,
                'weight_class_id'=>1,
                'length'=>0,
                'width'=>0,
                'height'=>0,
                'length_class_id'=>1,
                'tax_class_id'=>0,
                'product_description'=>array(
                    '1'=>array(
                        'description' => '',
                        'tag'=>'',
                        'meta_title'=>'Купить салют '.trim($product_data['name']),
                        'meta_description'=>'Купить салют '.trim($product_data['name']).' в интернет магазине фейерверков, пиротехники и салютов Оптсалют в розницу и оптом',
                        'meta_keyword' => 'Купить салют '.trim($product_data['name']).' в интернет магазине фейерверков, пиротехники и салютов Оптсалют в розницу и оптом',
                        'meta_h1'=>trim($product_data['name']),
                        'name'=>trim($product_data['name'])
                    )
                ),
                'subtract'=>0,
                'points'=>0,
                'sort_order'=>1,
                'shipping'=>1,

                'product_store'=>array('0'=>0)


            ));
```